# How to Fix a Different First Page Margin Under the Letter Class?

Tags: margins, geometry, letters

I would like to make a simple letter with the following margin: `left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[reset, a4paper, left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\date{}
\signature{Lorem Ipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Dear Lorem Ipsum,}

\lipsum

\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The MWE result is as following:

[image: \showframe shows extra line space at the first page.]

Here is the `\layout`:

[image: \layout of the letter document]

I realize that the first page "margin" differs from the next pages, but the margin frame is correct as shown in the `\showframe`. The first word doesn't want to start at the top of the body frame. The only things start at the top of the body is the sender information, such as the return address and the date. However, I want to omit those information (or at least make those information `\raggedleft`, but it failed). How could I address this problem?

Comment: Technically, the first page margin is the same as every other page.  The difference is a gap is added at the top of the first page, probably by \begin{letter}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a letter with your own settings, it's better to just use `article` - it'll allow you to format content to your specifications with the code also being much easier to read.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  paper = a4paper,
  margin=1in,
  noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}

\pagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent

\begin{document}

Dear Lorem Ipsum,

\bigskip

\lipsum

\bigskip

Yours sincerely,

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems there isn't an easy workaround on using the letter class. Article class gives me a more modular usage while still be easy to use on this case.

Comment: @Niki: Classes are meant to restrict certain usages as it's usually derived for a very specific purpose. Packages, on the other hand, are meant to expand/extend certain capabilities. So, starting with one of the base classes (like `article`) and only using packages allows you to create a flexible environment.